# PHP - Comparing form value with values in an array

Tags: php, text, compare, document

I'm trying to write a code that compares the values from a text document with a value that has been posted from a form.

So far i've got this, but i'm absolutely positive i'm doing something way off.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
<form method="POST" action="file.php"> 
<p>
<br /><input type="text" name="name" ><br />
</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Check" /></p>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];

    /*The text document contains these written names: 
    Michael 
    Terry 
    John 
    Phillip*/ 

    $lines = file('names.txt'); 

    $names_array = ($lines);   

        if (in_array($name, $names_array)) {
            echo "exists";
        } else {
            echo 'none';
        }
}
?>
```

**UPDATE: Fixed and now working fine!**

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> ```
> /*The text document contains these written names: 
> Michael 
> Terry 
> John 
> Phillip*/ 
>
> $lines = file('data.txt'); //Lets say we got an array with these values   //$lines =array('Michael','John','Terry','Phillip');    $i=0;
> foreach($lines as $line)   {
> $lines[$i] =trim($line);
> $i++;   }    
>
>     if (in_array($name, $lines)) {
>         echo "exists";
>     } else {
>         echo 'none';
>     } } ?
> ```
>
> > Blockquote
> >
> > data.txt
> >
> > Michael    Terry    John   Phillip
> >
> > data.txt has spaces ,so we use trim() to remove it.

Comment: Thanks for your help, now everything is working exactly the way i need it to! 

Marked as answer!

Comment: Thats just a terrible solution. First of all its not needed to loop through all the lines. Then to solve it you add the trimmed version to the end of the array, making it twice the length. So you end up with all names double in the list, once with and once without newline char. And you also add a random $i you are increasing for no reason at all.

Comment: @HugoDelsing - I'm really new to PHP, so if the answer above is bloated with unnecessary code, thanks for pointing it out! I tried your advice in adding 'ignore new lines' however it still didn't work for me. ie outputting none instead of exists. Any other ideas?

Comment: array(4) { [0]=> string(7) "Michael" [1]=> string(5) "Terry" [2]=> string(4) "John" [3]=> string(7) "Phillip" }

Comment: Try it yourself Niladri: `$lines = array("test", "test2");foreach($lines as $line) { $lines[] = $line;}var_dump($lines);` and you'll notice that you will have 4 keys in the final dump.

Comment: check the above code ,and it works : $lines[$i] =trim($line);

Comment: Your edit to include the `$i` doesnt realy make it much better because the indexing could be of if you modified it between the `file` statement and the `foreach`. If you want to do it like that atleast use `foreach($lines as $key=>$line) { $lines[$key]=trim($line); }`

Comment: @CMichael > If it works for you, just use it. As you mention you are new to PHP you should first spent your time in learning the logic instead of optimizing everything. I don't know why the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` didnt work for you, as its ment to do just that. My problem is that if somebody were to copy this answer and started doing something else, he would run into strange behaviour

Comment: @HugoDelsing - As it does work, in my situation, i hope that anyone coming across this reads the comments associated to this answer. 

Thanks again for your help!

Comment: one solution could be better , if any one use @file_open() and fgets()

Comment: each fgets() try to remove any spaces <-- Hint if you need a other soln.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your `file('names.txt')` function. Although this returns an array with each line in a seperate key, it also includes the newline charactor on that same line.

So your array actually contains:

```
$lines[0] = "Michael\n";
$lines[1] = "Terry\n";
$lines[2] = "John\n";
$lines[3] = "Phillip\n";
```

To prevent this from happening, use `file('names.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)`

```
$lines[0] = "Michael";
$lines[1] = "Terry";
$lines[2] = "John";
$lines[3] = "Phillip";
```

Now your name should match.

Besides that, why do you use the following?

```
$lines = file('names.txt'); 
$names_array = ($lines);

//simply use the following.
$names_array = file('names.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Comment: Yep, just realised that i was making more work for myself there! Fixed it up! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Read the doc about `file` : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

> Note:
>
> Each line in the resulting array will include the line ending, unless FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES is used, so you still need to use rtrim() if you do not want the line ending present.